# Given the curve $y = \sqrt x + 2$. Find a point on the curve where the tangent line is parallel to $y = \frac{1}{3} x − 10$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Given the curve $y = \sqrt{x}+ 2$. Find a point on the curve where the tangent line is
parallel to $y = \frac{1}{3}x − 10$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You're much more likely to get help if you let people know what you've tried and where you're getting stuck; that way, we can address the ACTUAL question you have, instead of just solving your problem for you. :-)

Comment: Iv'e edited your post. Please ensure it is written as supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The gradient of the other line is clearly $m=\frac{1}{3}$.

Evaluate the derivative with respect to $x$ of the curve $y=\sqrt{x}+2$ and let $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The slope of tangent of the curve $y = \sqrt{x} + 2$ is given by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, viz.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.
$$

The other curve, $y = \frac13 x - 10$, is a straight line given in the form $y=mx+c$, where $m$ is the slope of the line. For the tangent of the first curve to be parallel to the straight line,

$$
m = \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\implies x = \frac94.
$$

Hence, the corresponding point on the curve is $(9/4, 5)$.